# ¿Cómo fijar íconos dentro de un INPUT al reducir el ancho de la ventana?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, font-awesome

Tengo este pequeño inconveniente...

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña ventana de Login "responsive".

Y dentro de esta ventana, deseo que los íconos que se encuentran "dentro" de los INPUTS, permanezcan fijos al reducir el ancho de la ventana para un diseño Responsive.

Ya que al reducir el ancho de la ventana, éstos no se quedan fijos.
Ya que al reducir el ancho de la ventana, éstos no se quedan fijos.

**(Actualizado)**

```css
    
      body, html {  
          height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

#container {
    width: 98%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

#hijo-1, #hijo-2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#hijo-1 {
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}

#hijo-2 {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#hijo-2 > .form-input {
    position: relative;
}

#hijo-2 > .form-input > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    left: 164px;
}

input:not(input[type="submit"]){
    height: 33px;
    width: 190px;
    text-indent: 4px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <div id="container">
          <div id="hijo-1">
              <span>SYSTEM</span>
          </div>      
          <form id="hijo-2">
            <div>
                <img src="" alt="loguito">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">        
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>    
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese user" autocomplete="off"/>          
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i>
                <input type="password"  placeholder="Ingrese pass"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

[image: Demo]

*(Disculpen la calidad del .gif, espero que se pueda entender el problema)*

Comment: Agrega el resto del css de los inputs, el cual hace el efecto que el icono está dentro del textbox

Comment: Agregado. Todo eso es el código que "coloca" al ícono dentro del INPUT.

Comment: Pero también te falta el código que lo hace responsivo. Debes poner el código suficiente para reproducir el problema

Comment: Edité tu pregunta y puse el código para que se pudiera ejecutar desde la página. Si te fijas, los iconos están a la derecha y tu gif los muestra a la izquierda y tampoco tiene el problema de la responsividad que tu señalas

Comment: Espero que ahora sirva...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un ".form-input" que su width es el 100% del cuadro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, asignar la posición absoluta del icono se vuelve un lio, porque el tamaño cambia ya que es responsivo.

Una solución es dejar el width como auto, fit-content, max-content o max-content, cualquiera de estas en tu caso debería funcionar, luego un margin: 0 auto; para centrarlo. Y por último setear el left del icono acorde al nuevo cambio

```css
body, html {  
          height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

#container {
    width: 98%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

#hijo-1, #hijo-2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#hijo-1 {
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}

#hijo-2 {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#hijo-2 > .form-input {
    position: relative;
    width: min-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#hijo-2 > .form-input > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    left: 14px;
}

input:not(input[type="submit"]){
    height: 33px;
    width: 190px;
    text-indent: 4px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <div id="container">
          <div id="hijo-1">
              <span>SYSTEM</span>
          </div>      
          <form id="hijo-2">
            <div>
                <img src="" alt="loguito">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">        
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>    
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese user" autocomplete="off"/>          
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i>
                <input type="password"  placeholder="Ingrese pass"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```